# What do I use to seal or fix decoupage artwork?

Tags: decoupage-glue

I've made a couple of coasters using the decoupage technique, but they keep sticking in to one another. I used mod podge to seal the tissue and I'm assuming that is whats causing the stickiness. How do I seal or fix this?

Comment: Maybe, try clear acrylic sealant?

Comment: Is this a liquid or a spray? Would it react with the glue? I tried fixative and the glue started melting.

Comment: It's a spray, comes in a can like spray paints. I don't think it will react with the glue, would just add a top layer to the product. You could try on a tiny part first to check, though

Comment: @BellaSwan No, that won't work because acryllic never truely dries. It always retains a little amount of moisture and reacts to air humidity, which makes it stick just like the current solution. That's why you should never store acryllic artworks with the paint touching directly, but always put a seperating sheet between them.

Comment: How long have they been tacky? Mod Podge needs a month or two to fully cure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to clear epoxy resin, you have other alternatives depending on what material you are working your decoupage art on. 
And often based on the shape of your object also. Like, Epoxy resin isn't a good option in case of curved surfaces.

For coasters made of wood/mdf/acrylic, you may want to use **[Liquitex's Matte Varnish](https://www.liquitex.com/row/products/professional/gessoes-mediums-varnishes/matte-varnish/)** to give it a non-shiny, matte finish.

On glass bottles and decoration objects, you may want to use **[DecoArt's Triple Thick Gloss Glaze](https://shop.decoart.com/triple-thick-gloss-glaze)** to give it a shiny glossy finish.

More suggestions would include:

1. water based: MINWAX's Polycrylic
2. oil based: MINWAX's Polyurethane

Answer (score 1):

You can coat your coasters with a layer of clear resin. Here is a [good instructional video on YouTube](https://youtu.be/qQrRVUarzPc) on how to coat surfaces using clear resin.

Comment: the video isn't available, pls confirm if this is taken down or is it just me facing the issue?